# How do I calculate the width and height of a bitmap from this file header?

Tags: image, bitmap, graphic

```
00000000 42 4D 3A FE 05 00 00 00-00 00 36 04 00 00 28 00
00000010 00 00 D1 02 00 00 1D 02-00 00 01 00 08 00 00 00 
00000020 00 00 04 FA 05 00 13 0B-00 00 13 0B 00 00 00 00
```

What are the values of width and height?

Comment: Do you think you describe your problem well enough? There is even no background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia - BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

```
Offset (hex)    Offset (dec)    Size (bytes)    Windows BITMAPINFOHEADER[1]
0E              14              4               the size of this header (40 bytes)
12              18              4               the bitmap width in pixels (signed integer)
16              22              4               the bitmap height in pixels (signed integer)
```

With the bitmap header you posted, the width and height would be

```
Width:  D1 02 00 00
Height: 1D 02 00 00
```

The Wikipedia link above states that

> All of the integer values are stored in little-endian format (i.e.
>   least-significant byte first).

If my understanding is correct, that converts to

```
 Width = 209 + (2 x 256) + (0 x 256^2) + (0 x 256^3) = 721
Height =  29 + (2 x 256) + (0 x 256^2) + (0 x 256^3) = 541
```

Comment: Why multiply with 256?

Comment: Each of width and height are a 4 byte integer. 8 bits per byte so 2^8 (256) possible values for each byte. So basically it's a base 256 integer (with the bytes in reverse order due to being little endian). So e.g. in base 10, the number 1250 can be represented as 0 + 5x10 + 2x10^2 + 1x10^3. In the base 256 little endian integer the first byte is 0-255, the second byte is the number of full 256's, etc.